# Can't compile with module and main program in same file

Tags: fortran

I am trying to make use of a module that is in the same file as my main program. However, I cannot get it to work. Does Fortran allow a module to be contained in the same file as the main program or must it be in a separate file? Here is a simple version of my code:

```
main program
  use my_module
  call my_subroutine()
end program main

module my_module
  contains
    subroutine my_subroutine()
      print *, "Hello World!"
    end subroutine my_subroutine
end module my_module
```

When I try to compile this file I get:

```
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'my_module.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Fortran does allow modules to be contained in the same file as the main program. However, modules must be written before the main program:

```
module my_module
  contains
    subroutine my_subroutine()
      print *, "Hello World!"
    end subroutine my_subroutine
end module my_module

program main
  use my_module
  call my_subroutine()
end program main
```

Comment: To be really nitpicking: the rule says something different. It says that module modules must placed before they are used. This is legal Fortran: `call s;
end;
module m;
end module;
subroutine s;
  use m;
end`

Comment: @VladimirF You are correct. Good catch on that. Impressive!

Comment: You can also `include 'my_module.fx'` before the main program instead of adding the module code explicitly.

Comment: I put the module after the main program, I can still use it. why?