# Explicit interface required for subroutines

Tags: makefile, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to compile a package written mainly in F90 that looks like this:

```
subroutine soil_default_fill(cgrid,ifm,ipy)

implicit none
!----- Arguments -----------------------------------------------------------------------!
type(edtype) , target       :: cgrid
integer      , intent(in)   :: ifm
integer      , intent(in)   :: ipy
!----- Local variables -----------------------------------------------------------------!

STUFF

return
end subroutine soil_default_fill
!==========================================================================================!


subroutine set_site_defprops()

   implicit none 
   !----- Local variables -----------------------------------------------------------------!
   type(edtype)     , pointer :: cgrid
   integer                    :: ifm
   integer                    :: ipy

STUFF
         call soil_default_fill(cgrid,ifm,ipy)

         STUFF


   return
end subroutine set_site_defprops
!==========================================================================================!
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

```
mpif90 -c -DUSE_INTERF=1 -DUSENC=0 -DMAC_OS_X -DUSE_HDF5=1 -DUSE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO=0 -DUSE_MPIWTIME=0 -O3 -ffree-line-length-none -fno-whole-file  -I/Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/src/include -I/usr/hdf5/include   -DRAMS_MPI ed_init.F90

ed_init.F90:131.31:

         call soil_default_fill(cgrid,ifm,ipy)
                               1
Error: Explicit interface required for 'soil_default_fill' at (1): target argument
make[1]: *** [ed_init.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I already tried to include the subroutine in an interface or in a module but it didn't worked (as I said I am new to Fortran so it is likely that I made some mistakes).

Thanks for help

Comment: Read the first answer here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083380/cant-compile-with-module-and-main-program-in-same-file  -- to find out how to structure a source file containing a module and the main program.  The simply write your main program including `use module` and the compiler will take care of creating the interface required.

Comment: That file (ED_init.F90) does not contain the main.

Comment: Doing so produces a lot of compilation errors, for example if in the body of the subroutine (where there is STUFF) there was:

    `integer :: a`

   `a = 1+1`

I would get the error

`subroutine soil_default_fill(cgrid,ifm,ipy)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
ed_init.F90:722.50:

a = 1+1
                                                  1`

and others such as `Error: Unexpected assignment statement in MODULE at (1)`

`Error: Unexpected DO statement in MODULE at (1)`

etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple answer but,
Did you set up your module file like this example?

```
!----------------------------------------------------------!

module "Your Name here (without commas)"

use  a_module   !!! if you need one, in the other case delete it
use  b_module   !!! if you need another one, in the other case delete it

implicit none

public :: set_site_defprops  !!! put a comment here if you want
public :: soil_default_fill  !!! put a comment here if you want

contains

subroutine soil_default_fill(cgrid,ifm,ipy)

implicit none
!----- Arguments ----------------------------------------------------------!
type(edtype) , target       :: cgrid
integer      , intent(in)   :: ifm
integer      , intent(in)   :: ipy
!----- Local variables ----------------------------------------------------!

STUFF

return
end subroutine soil_default_fill
!==============================================================================!


subroutine set_site_defprops()

   implicit none 
   !----- Local variables -------------------------------------------------!
   type(edtype)     , pointer :: cgrid
   integer                    :: ifm
   integer                    :: ipy

STUFF
         call soil_default_fill(cgrid,ifm,ipy)

         STUFF


   return
end subroutine set_site_defprops
!==============================================================================!


end module "Your Name here (without commas)"
```

Comment: Yes, as I said in the last 4th comment of my post, doing so produces compilation errors every line.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the configuration now for compiling ? Since the one you showed us has no link to the module

Comment: The problem is that my file has many more subroutines inside it, I do not really know which objects should be public and if it is safe to do so.

Comment: I think that now you are moving the question....

What is behind having some objects public or not I think that is not related with your first question.

What you use now for compile ?

`mpif90 -c -DUSE_INTERF=1 -DUSENC=0 -DMAC_OS_X -DUSE_HDF5=1 -DUSE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO=0 -DUSE_MPIWTIME=0 -O3 -ffree-line-length-none -fno-whole-file  -I/Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/src/include -I/usr/hdf5/include   -DRAMS_MPI ed_init.F90`

Comment: I am using openmpi so the mpif90 (it is actually an alias to mpifort) is needed. The rest are options and the paths to the headers.